# Attempting to parse an XML and get info onto a GUI

Tags: java, xml, swing, user-interface

I am trying to get my parsed XML data onto my GUI that I am making. The goal is to click the "Open connection" button (which has the code in it from the class Open Connection) to open the connecting to the XML webpage, then use the "Get Headlines" button (which has the code in it from the NPRInfo class) to get the Titles and Descriptions of the articles to show up in the text box. Ignore the Keyword button for now, I will start working on that once I fix this problem. Can anybody please point out what I am doing wrong and how I can go about fixing it? Thanks for any and all help!

```
//import java.io.*;
//import java.io.BufferedReader;
//import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;


public class NPRNews extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton btnURL;
    JButton btnKW;
    JButton btnTD;
    JTextArea txtArea;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new NPRNews();
    }
    public NPRNews() throws Exception {
        super("NPR News");
        setupGUI();
        NPRInfo();
        registerListeners();
    }

    public void NPRInfo() throws Exception {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory XmlBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder xBuilder = XmlBuilder.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xml = xBuilder.parse(new URL("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001").openStream());
            if(xml==null)
                System.out.println("no XML DOM Document retrieved.");
                xml.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nList = xml.getElementsByTagName("item");
            if(nList==null)
                System.out.println("No elements with tag name channel retrieved.");

            int temp = 0;
            for (temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    txtArea.setText("Title : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                    txtArea.setText("Description : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                    txtArea.setText("------------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void setupGUI() {
        JPanel pnlCanvas = new JPanel();
        btnURL = new JButton("Connect to NPR");
        pnlCanvas.add(btnURL);
        btnKW = new JButton("NPR Keywords");
        pnlCanvas.add(btnKW);
        btnTD = new JButton("NPR Headlines");
        pnlCanvas.add(btnTD);
        txtArea = new JTextArea();
        pnlCanvas.add(txtArea);
        pnlCanvas.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Container mainPanel = this.getContentPane();
        mainPanel.add(pnlCanvas, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanel.add(txtArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        this.setSize(500, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void registerListeners(){
        btnURL.addActionListener(this);
        btnKW.addActionListener(this);
        btnTD.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void openConnection() throws Exception{
        URL url = new URL("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        if (e.getSource() == btnURL) {
            try {
                this.openConnection();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btnTD) {
            try {
                this.NPRInfo();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: When I click the button on the GUI, nothing happens. It should show up with only the titles and descriptions, it works just fine on system.out, but not on the gui text area. the only thing that shows up in the text area is -----------------------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `JTextArea#setText`, use `JTextArea#append` instead.

`setText` does just that, changes the text of the text area to what ever you specify, discarding what ever was previous applied to it.

Comment: Okay, that posted more of what I wanted, but it cuts off now. Do I need to make a scroll bar or something? Another thing, is there I way I can make that show up only after I hit the "headlines" button? Right now it shows up right as I run the program.

Comment: Add the text area to a scroll pane

Comment: See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: Let me rephrase, I misunderstood my own problem. After each title/description, I want it to skip a line down, right now it just has all of the information on a single line.

Comment: Okay, now you need to add a `"\n"` to the end of each line.  `JTextArea` doesn't "magically" know when it should introduce a new line ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's my fault I completely forgot such a simple thing. Now, my final question. How can I make the text only show up after I hit my "headlines" button?